# Substitution failure sometimes is an error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

It seems that substitution failure sometimes is an error. 
Could someone tell me when it will be an error and when it will not? 
See run result [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/29sdst%240) 
Thank you!

Thank you for the informative answer! 
This code doens't compile with g++ 4.8, but works as expected with clang++ 3.2, g++ 4.7.3 and intel 13.0.1.
So now I'm sure this is a bug to g++ 4.8. I have reported this to gcc bugzila.

```
In substitution of ‘template<class C> static constexpr int has<T>::test(decltype (sizeof (C:: x))) [with C = C; T = foo] [with C = foo]’:
required from ‘const int has<foo>::value’
required from here
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘std::string foo::x()’
```

The code

```
template <typename T>
struct has {
    template <typename>
    constexpr static int test(...) {
      return 0;
    }
    template <typename C>
    constexpr static int test(decltype(sizeof(C::x))) {  // Doesn't compile.
      return 1;   // Is a member variable.
    }
    template <typename C, int c =
        sizeof(decltype(((C*)nullptr)->x()))>
    constexpr static int test(int) {
      return 2;   // Is a member function.
    }
    static const int value = test<T>(0);
};

struct foo {
    string x();
};
struct bar {
    string x;
};
int main() {
    std::cout << has<int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has<foo>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has<bar>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your error is ' invalid use of non-static member function ‘std::string foo::x()’', so the problem comes from your method not being static while you try to access it in a static way.

Comment: Works on Clang 3.2 I believe this is a bug

Answer (score 4):

The rule is essentially that the error must depend on a template parameter of the declaration which it immediately belongs to.

This example looks like a compiler bug. It doesn't correctly not-an-error out the particular syntax flaw.

If you want it to return success when the class has a nonstatic member function named `x`, you should use `&C::x`, because you're allowed to take a pointer to a member function but not simply to name it as a standalone subexpression.

My preferred way to do this would be

```
template< typename, typename = void >
struct has_x
    : std::false_type {};

template< typename t >
struct has_x< t, typename std::enable_if< & t::x == & t::x >::type >
    : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: I expand my code some more. I want to check is a given name a member variable or a member function.